# image file /assets/image folder dissapear when I build with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

This is a  **REACT APP**

When i using *npm run build* , the folder images dissapear from *./assets*

the images not find in the *./assets*

I don't know why messing the image. This image using in css background

**This is my webpack.common.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

// Production
const PROD_URL = path.join(__dirname, "./dist");
const PROD_ASSETS_DIR = PROD_URL+'/assets';

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/Index.js',
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: '我们开始旅行吧',
            template: "./index.html"
        })
    ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader:"url-loader",
            // loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192&name=assets/images/[hash:8].[name].[ext]',
            options: {
              limit: 8192,
              outputPath: "dist/asstes/",
              publicPath: "/dist/" 
            },
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**This is my webpack.prod.js**

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js')
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = merge(webpackConfig, {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJSPlugin()
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you lose this folder: “./dist/assets/images”. Here's the answer.

You are using CleanWebpackPlugin. It removes all content from the "./dist" folder before building. After that, the url loader collects and places all the images in the ./dist/assets folder. This is why your "images" folder disappears.